# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 show error while installation

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have tried several times to install the **Microsoft SQL Server 2014** by using *iso* file but it shows following error message.

"The patch file cannot be opened...... Error code: 0x84B20001"

I have tried the solution from site to fix the problem by Unzip the setup folder and then started the installation but it still didn't work and showed the same error message.

I have tried this site for the problem solution: [Microsoft SQL Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/18806293-ac9a-472e-aaba-5d862ad4b857/sql-server-enterprise-core-2012-sp1-setup-failure?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: I believe that error stems from a failed prior install.  Not really enough details here.  What does "I have tried the solution from site to fix" mean? What site?  This site?  Reference the question.  As it stands we likely cannot assist you here.

Comment: I have tried this site for the problem solution:
[Microsoft SQL Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/18806293-ac9a-472e-aaba-5d862ad4b857/sql-server-enterprise-core-2012-sp1-setup-failure?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)